# unittest testcase setup new object

Tags: python, eclipse, class, pydev, instantiation

I'm using pydev in Classic Eclipse 4.2.2 with Python2.7. Please consider the code and result below as you read.

Suppose I create an object with a variable of a predefined value. Now, suppose I change this value and create a new object of the same name (i.e., old name points to a new object). I would expect the old name to point to a new object whose value does not differ from the predefined value given in the class definition. That is not the case. Any suggestions as to why?

Code:

```
class example(object):

    veryImportantDict = {'A': 0}

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def set_veryImportantNumber(self,key,val):
        self.veryImportantDict[key] = val 

if __name__ == '__main__':

    test = example()
    print "New object: ", test
    print "New object's dict: ",test.veryImportantDict
    test.set_veryImportantNumber('A',5)
    print "Old object's dict: ",test.veryImportantDict
    test = example()
    print "New object: ", test
    print "New object's dict: ",test.veryImportantDict
```

Which returns:

```
New object: <__main__.example object at 0x0478C430> 
New object's dict:  {'A': 0} Old object's dict:  {'A': 5} 
New object: <__main__.example object at 0x0478C450> 
New object's dict:  {'A': 5}
```

Comment: It wouldn't let me post unless I treated the output as a code block, but it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're defining your attribute as a class variable. class vars will be shared among all instances of the class. You can think of it as a static attribute from other languages.

You need to define it as an instance variable, in this way:

```
class example(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.veryImportantDict = {'A': 0}

    def set_veryImportantNumber(self,key,val):
        self.veryImportantDict[key] = val
```

Also, you shouldn't define setter or getter methods until you really need them. Python as way to change this behaviour if you find out its necessary later on, so you can avoid the bloat of access methods and just access the attributes directly, like so:

```
class example(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.veryImportantDict = {'A': 0}

test.veryImportantDict['A'] = 'foo'
```

Comment: Thanks so much. And you weren't deterred by the fact that I forgot to name the post (it defaulted to the keywords I initially thought of)!

Answer (score 0):

By declaring `veryImportantDict`  in the class definition, you are making it a class variable. What you want is to create an instance variable. To do so, you just have to declare it in the constructor.

You can think of it this way: The class *declaration* itself is an object. `veryImportantDict` is a member of that object. If you change its value, you change the *definition* of the class. So the next time you create an object from that class, it will have the new value. If you set the value in the constructor instead, it will be a member of that object only.